# Neovim - How do you call Python from Lua and store the results as a Lua variable?

Tags: neovim, python, lua

I am trying to improve a GitHub repository for Neovim called

[quangnguyen30192/cmp-nvim-ultisnips](https://github.com/quangnguyen30192/cmp-nvim-ultisnips)

It's a Lua repository that calls another Vim plugin repository, [SirVer/ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) , a primarily Python-only library.

I basically need to call, in Python, `UltiSnips_Manager._snips('completion text here', True))`, and somehow get that list of string data back into Lua.

My plan was to imitate how UltiSnips does this, which is to [call the Python object and assign its return value to a global Vim variable and then access that variable later](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/66d81fc2c0bda30be69fffa46da0932ee8d5ddd5/autoload/UltiSnips.vim#L26). I just need to adapt the solution to work for Lua.

Here was my naive attempt at using `Lua` to call a `Python` function and send that data to a `Vim` variable so I could access it again, via `Lua`

```lua
vim.exec_python("""
import vim

snippets = UltiSnips_Manager._snips('completion text here', True)
snippet_names = [snipper.trigger for snippet in snippts]
vim.command(\"let g:_allowed_snippets = '%s'\" % snippet_names)
""")

print(vim.g._allowed_snippets)
```

That doesn't work, because exec_python isn't a real Lua function, as far as I can tell. If there's a way to call Python within Lua in Neovim, could someone please explain how to do that? Or if there's a simpler way to call a Python script that is "known" to Vim and get the data back as a Lua object could someone explain how that could be done?

Comment: have you tried vim.fn.pyeval ?

Comment: This is great, I forgot about that one. Thank you!